# Table that is obviously small enough cannot fit same page as chapter

Tags: tables, landscape, sidewaystable

Edit: I have included all packages from my document as well (I know there are too many. As I still am a beginner in Latex, I add every new package when I try something found on the forums).

I have a question regarding fitting tables. For my thesis I have to name all stakeholders, which I created an Appendix for. The table itself should fit the page in which the chapter title is located, however the table how much I try is put on a new page (even when I make the table way smaller using `\scriptsize`, it does not fit). The code I use is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.8in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks,draft]{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{varwidth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Chapter settings
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

%%% Add this %%%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0}{15pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{30pt}                  Original values
%\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt} Original values

%%%   End   %%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Project stakeholders} \label{app:stakeanal}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\textheight}
  \caption{Stakeholder analysis}\label{my-label}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Stakeholder} & \textbf{Position} & \textbf{Interest} &
  \textbf{Influence} & \textbf{Key interest} \\
  \midrule
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{varwidth}%
}
\end{table}
```

Can you guys help me fix it, it look so easy, yet it is so hard! I also tried using landscape, however this is also not possible as I do not want my chapter title to change from its top vertical position to top horizontal position.

Comment: Welcome, without checking the maual ... didn't `sidewaystable` *always* start on a new page? How about `rotating`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Since I am still quite new to writing in Latex (this is my first document), I still haven't figured out everything. After checking, I see that sidewaystable automatically puts it on a new page. Thanks. I tried using \rotatebox, however I could not rotate the caption alongside with it as well!. Any tips?

Comment: Try to avoid to rotate the table - that's bad for the reader. On a page with a chapter title the difference between remaining height and width isn't so large, so quite often it is possible to set the table in portrait.

Comment: You shouldn't modify your question that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sidewaystable` the float will *always* go to a new page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,varwidth}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Project stakeholders} \label{app:stakeanal}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\textheight}
  \caption{Stakeholder analysis}\label{my-label}
  \footnotesize

  \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Stakeholder} & \textbf{Position} & \textbf{Interest} &
  \textbf{Influence} & \textbf{Key interest} \\
  \midrule
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  Name & Position & Medium & High & Description \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{varwidth}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when I try to use the code you provided me in my document it still is not working. I edited my question and put my entire code there (with all packages I keep adding as I try out new ways to do something). Could you help find out the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @John: I had to remove `subfigure` and `chngcntr` packages because the clash with others. Then it compiled fine.

Comment: The `varwidth` will stop having an effect when the OP uses the `subcaption` package. I guess it adds a `minipage` with `\textwidth` or something else then for `\caption`. That's why it is larger then it should be after rotating.

Comment: Using the code provided (and keep the packages I have, exluding the clahsing ones) it still does not work for me. The table stays on the bottom of the 2nd page

Comment: @John: Remove the `subcaption` package and compare. Might also work with some other `subcaption` setting.

Comment: It works, thank you Martin! I decided to keep the \chngcntr as I do not want to my figures and tables to have the chapter letter inside the numbering (Figure 1, rather than Figure G.1)

Comment: @John, egrep: Correction, it's not the `subcaption` package itself but the underlying `caption` package. I couldn't find a suitable option in the manual to change this. Maybe someone other with more experience with `caption` can help.